# Prepositions - do I use "for" or "on" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

This is for my resume so I want to use the right preposition here . . .

"Researched and drafted judicial opinions **on/for** a wide variety of civil and criminal cases"

I cannot tell if I should use ON or FOR in this situation.

Later in my resume for another experience I have been using on . . .
"Researched and drafted reports and recommendations ***on*** a wide range of issues, including . . . "

Now I am confused and don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you research and draft judicial opinions for use in a wide variety of civil and criminal cases or did you research and draft judicial opinions on a wide variety of civil and criminal cases that were used elsewhere (i.e. after the fact)?

Answer (score 1):

They have different meanings:

*"Researched and drafted judicial opinions **on** a wide variety of civil and criminal cases"* means that you researched a large number of civil and criminal cases for some other project or entity - perhaps your boss wanted to know how many times the lawyers used a particular trick, and with that data he made a graph on his wall.

*"Researched and drafted judicial opinions **for** a wide variety of civil and criminal cases"* means that you were employed in a large variety of civil and criminal cases, and in each of those cases you researched and/or drafted judicial opinions.